# VBA Code to account for inserting of rows after the fact.

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been able to create checkboxes to show/hide specific rows in my excel document using the following Code

> ```
> If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Rows("26:28").EntireRow.Hidden = False
> If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Rows("26:28").EntireRow.Hidden = True
> ```

However I need to be able to have the range update when I insert rows above this range.

Was trying to find the cell on which the range starts and then adding 2 to the range but not quite sure how to do so.

Cheers

Robert

Comment: Mr. Robert Kemm you have really created havoc, "find the cell on which the range starts and then adding 2 to the range",,, please specify whether you want to add 2 to the cells of the range or trying to test the hidden Rows or insert the rows.

Comment: I think Robert's question is quite clear, on the contrary. It's not about adding 2 to a cell's value. What he is asking is, "how can I find the first cell of the range I want to hide (like `A26`), select the whole line (`26:26`), extend it by 2 lines (`26:28`) and show/hide those based on the checkbox' value". Not "how to add 2 to the value of those cells".

Answer (score 3):

Tracking and managing addition / deletion of rows could be extremely difficult (make sure to capture it always, also need to either modify the code itself for the new row number, or store it somewhere on a sheet...), I suggest to use some workaround.

1. Use a named range:  named ranges are shifted together with cells, so referring them will always refer to the same cells.

   - In below example A6:A7 is a named range and the sample code shows/hides it.

[image]

2. Another option could be to look for specific information in the spreadsheet and make your actions based on that, however it's again quite complex.

Answer (score 1):

*I'll assume you have a working code to show/hide those lines, and that your problem is only to find the line after you inserted lines above.*

If you have only one range to show/hide, you could use a named range. When new lines above, the named range will still point to the same lines.

Simply give a name (e.g. `ToBeHidden`) to a few cells (e.g. `A26:A28`, no need to name the whole lines), and use this code to toggle them:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("ToBeHidden").EntireRow
    If .Hidden = True Then
        .Hidden = False
    Else
        .Hidden = True
    End If
End With
```

It's easy with one set of lines to toggle, but if you have many, you'll need something more powerful. Perhaps add a dedicated column to activate this feature.

Comment: ,,your comment to my post "adding 2 to the range" was different and now you have shown him how to Test whether the Named Range is hidden or not ?

Comment: Rajesh, I think you should reread the initial question. I'm afraid you got it wrong!

Answer (score -2):

Since the goal of the OP is,"to detect whether and how many rows are inserted", which you can find in the comments above from Máté Juhász, then, the solution should track the hidden data range for rows inserted or deleted.

First, name the hidden range `A26:A28` and use the following VBA code to track the number of rows inserted or deleted.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static lngRow As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("Named Range").RefersToRange
    If lngRow = 0 Then
    lngRow = rng1.Row
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If rng1.Row = lngRow Then Exit Sub
    If rng1.Row < lngRow Then
        MsgBox lngRow - rng1.Row & " Row Deleted"
    Else
        MsgBox rng1.Row - lngRow & " Rows Inserted"
    End If
    lngRow = rng1.Row
End Sub
```

Note: If you only want to count rows inserted then change the last `If...` to

```
If rng1.Row > lngRow Then
    MsgBox rng1.Row - lngRow & " Rows Inserted"
End If
```

Comment: I think you are trying to prove something irrelevant, but frankly I'm not sure what. OP refers to the rows 26..28 as the range they need to adjust, according to number of rows eventually added (or perhaps sometimes removed) above that range. Using a `named range` as has been suggested by the others, is certainly the right way, since it automatically corrects the row references with addition/deletion of rows above.

Comment: Everyone has a different perception,,, Mate Jahsaz determined the KEY and what I've suggested !! This is really frustrating ,, **better should be , wait for the OP to finalize the issue,,, :-)** and i can bet that OP will never Return to the post as usual problem here !!

Comment: Rajesh, the only one here who "has a different perception" is you. And you're wrong again, as usual.

Comment: Unfortunately the discussion above has been removed. You asked for an "honest reply", and I think it's important for you to hear it.  Here is my [honest reply](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5bso9jx3c42krt/Comment.rtf?dl=0) about your answer, and about your behavior on this site in general.

Comment: Thanks for response, I received what exactly I was expecting,, nothing new  I don't  like to disengage my self. My simple suggestion is just ignore my post. thanks again , take care.

Comment: So, why don't you change your behavior? You were doing very good for a while, but then you went back to your old ways.  Surely you don't enjoy having most of your answers down voted?  You could make a positive contribution here if you would just listen to people when they try to point you in the correct direction.